# Term for a method used in solving equations

Tags: terminology, mathematics

Suppose we have an equation:

[image: equation]

To solve for *x*, we would **single it out because it appears in both summands**. And so we get:

[image: x]

I am wondering what is this step called in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant term is ***to factor out***. For example:

> To solve for *x,* we factor it out because it appears in both summands.

For reasons that are beyond me, I could not find this usage documented in dictionaries; so here are some example usages:

- [*How to factor out numbers*](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/algebra/how-to-factor-out-numbers/) from Dummies.
- From the [distributive property on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Real_numbers):

  > Since the factor 6*a*²*b* occurs in all summands, it can be factored out.
- [Tons of examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22factor%20out%22) from Mathematics Stack Exchange.